# Babel config file in .mjs format does not work when using the function parameter api

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader

I am looking into converting my current `babel.config.js` file to a `babel.config.mjs` file. This should be straight forward but for some reason I am getting the following error when I try to use the function parameter `api` in my configuration:

> Cannot change caching after evaluation has completed.

Here is my config, pretty barebones:

```js
export default function(api) {
  api.cache(true) // if I remove this then it will work
  return {
    plugins,
    presets
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

api.cache(true), enables caching for the Babel configuration.  The error is often tied to modifying the babel configuration caching after evaluation.

In a .babelrc.mjs or babel.config.mjs file, api.cache shouldn’t be used as the module-based configuration is cached by Node.js. so no need for manual enabling  caching.

the fix should be to remove the api.cache(true) line:

export default function() {
return {
plugins,
presets
};
}

Hopefully, this should fix the issue. I hope it does.